# Separated Character Generation convert from IBM i series (AS400) to Java text file

Tags: java, ibm-midrange, cobol, rpgle

I'm trying to create an "XLS" file, but it will be available as a txt file. (It means when you right click and select open with in windows and choose notepad it will show as tab separated text file.)

This is the sample file that I'm trying to create (I have to remove some entry because it is big). When you open the file in notepad++ and choose encoding in UTF-8, you will see "hidden characters" like the picture below:
[image]

If you can see xA0 that is one of the hidden characters that is generated by a COBOL program of the IBM I Series (AS400).

However, if you see those yellow highlighted part, that is also a character of the AS400. It was declared like this below:

```
DCL VAR(&FLDDLM)     TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(1)    VALUE(X'05')
```

Now I was able to generate the xA0 with these test code below:

```
List<Object[]> data = new ArrayList<>();
data.add(new Object[] { "AS1", "185914", "NETHERLANDS", "NL", "", "202023714", "2023714", "27-AUG-2022",
        "03-FEB-2023", "", "", "00000000", "IF-ADAMAS", "", "PTF166091NL00",
        "P166091NL00", "", "", "", "", "IF ADAMAS B V" });
data.add(new Object[] { "AS1", "20200893", "GERMANY", "DE", "", "13801864.3", "2915188",
        "05-NOV-2022", "22-FEB-2023", "R80049", "10", "00000434", "MICRONIT M", "",
        "PTF124241DEEP", "P118354DEEP", "", "", "", "",
        "MICRONIT MICROFLUIDICS B.V." });

OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("output.XLS"),"windows-1252");

writer.write(
        "\"Client\"\t\"Case Number\"\t\"Country\"\t\"WIPO\"\t\"Subcase\"\t\"Application Number\"\t\"Patent Number\"\t\"Due Date\"\t\"Paid Date\"\t\"Invoice Number\"\t\"Annuity Number\"\t\"Invoice Amount\"\t\"Client/Division\"\t\"Client Ref(Inv)\"\t\"Client Ref#1(Ctry)\"\t\"Client Ref#2(Ctry)\"\t\"Attorney(Inv)\"\t\"Attorney(Ctry)\"\t\"Remarks\"\t\"Local Title\"\t\"Title Holder\"\n");

for (Object[] row : data) {
    for (int i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
        writer.write("\"" + "\u00a0" + row[i].toString() + "\"");
        if (i < row.length - 1) {
            writer.write("\t");
        }
    }
    writer.write("\n");
}

writer.close();
System.out.println("Done");

}
```

I must put in the `"windows-1252"` in `FileOutputStream("output.XLS"),"windows-1252");` to generate the `xA0` with `"\u00a0"` like you see in the picture above. However,

DCL VAR(&FLDDLM)     TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(1)    VALUE(X'05')

I put in the `"\u0005"` instead of simple `"\t"` in the

```
            if (i < row.length - 1) {
                writer.write("\t");
            }
```

It gives me `ENQ` like this picture below

[image]

That is not what I want to achieve. I want to achieve like the first picture.
Thus, can someone tell me what is the equivalent of `X'05'` field separator? What should I change?
Can someone help me with this please?

I would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You might want to Google ASCII table, and EBCDIC table. That way you can determine these mappings yourself. But anyway, you can find an EBCDIC table [here](https://www.cs.umd.edu/%7Emeesh/cmsc311/clin-cmsc311/Lectures/lecture6/ebcdic.html) and an ASCII table [here](https://www.asciitable.com/). If you look for TAB or horizontal tab, you will find that it is x05 in EBCDIC, and x09 in ASCII. Since windows-1252 is an ASCII code, you should be loading \u0009 into the file.